# Translate and rotate matrix via old matrix values

Tags: java, android, matrix, rotation, translate-animation

I am trying to rotate and translate my bitmap with a matrix where I use the following code (I tried making it plain english):

```
playerX = playerValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
playerY = playerValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

if (fingerx1 > playerX) {
    xspeed = 1;

}
if (fingerx1 < playerX) {
    xspeed = -1;
}
if (fingery1 < playerY) {
    yspeed = -1;
}
if (fingery1 > playerY) {
    yspeed = 1;
}

//playerX and playerY are checked in Log.d, returns correct values

playerMatrix.setRotate(rotation, bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2);
playerX += xspeed;
playerY += yspeed;
playerValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X] = playerX;
playerValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] = playerY;
playerMatrix.setValues(playerValues);
```

This does not work :P It flashes back and forth between the start and current x and y values. Could anyone tell me what the right way of doing this translation?

(rotation works fine alone)

Comment: I assume it has to do with the points being moved when rotated as well as manually translated as so... or I am just completely off.  I would love to hear an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Matrix.setXXX() will replace the previous matrix transformations. Instead of setValues, you can use:

```
playerMatrix.postRotate(rotation, bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2);
playerX += xspeed;
playerY += yspeed;
playerValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X] = playerX;
playerValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] = playerY;
playerMatrix.postTranslate(playerX, playerY);
```